# 32-bit or 64-bit version of Microsoft Office on Windows 7 64-bit bootcamp?

Tags: bootcamp, ms-office, windows, microsoft

I wanted to ask which version I should download and install. First, I need to tell you that I use Windows 7 64-bit bootcamp on my Mac. I access it mostly via a virtual machine (VMWare). My Macbook has 8GB RAM and an about 3.1 GHz processor. I have about 10GB of free space on my bootcamp. Which version of Microsoft office should I install, 32-bit or 64-bit? Does 32-bit even work on my bootcamp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Microsoft support page](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Choose-the-32-bit-or-64-bit-version-of-Office-2dee7807-8f95-4d0c-b5fe-6c6f49b8d261#BKMK_Limitations64bit) describes the limitations of the 64bit office.

They are the following:

- Solutions using ActiveX controls library, ComCtl controls won’t work.
- Third-party ActiveX controls and add-ins won’t work.
- Visual Basic for Applications (VBA) that contain Declare statements won’t work in the 64-bit version of Office without being updated.
- Compiled Access databases, like .MDE and .ACCDE files, won’t work unless they’re specifically written for the 64-bit version of Office.
- In SharePoint, the list view won’t be available.
- If you have specific add-ins that you use in the 32-bit version of Office, they may not work in 64-bit Office, and vice versa. If you’re concerned, check your current version of Office before installing the new one. Considering testing the add-in with 64-bit Office, or finding out if a 64-bit version of the add-in is available from the developer.

If these limitations do not apply to you (they seem quite advanced and/or obscure to me) then you should choose the 64bit option.

The 32bit version will work as Microsoft is usually quite good in support of older windows versions and architectures, but there is really no benefit to it.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I wasn't really sure which one to choose. I'll install the 64-bit version now.